# Should I reorganize the main service panel when adding a subpanel?

Tags: electrical, subpanel

I am currently in need of a new 240V circuit for a welder in the garage but my main breaker is full.  Adding a subpanel seems to be the only solution that would be to code, but I have a couple questions on the specifics.

First, There is already a subpanel that is powering the basement, but its distance from the garage makes running 10-3 cable a bit difficult.  Is it ok to have two subpanels?

Second, assuming I could install another subpanel, how should I reorganize the circuits?  Would it be a good idea to move all lighting and misc (15A-20A) circuits to the new subpanel and keep the existing/new 240V circuits in the main breaker panel?

Comment: The answer may be different depending one whether you live in the USA, UK, Australia, India, Canada, China or Azerbaijan. It can help to mention your location.

Answer (score 2):

It's nearly impossible for anybody to tell you if you can safely add a second subpanel, based on the information you've provided.  It's going to depend on the service capacity, and how loaded the service already is.

Your best bet would be to contact a local licensed Electrician, and have them do an estimate on adding the new subpanel.  They will come take a look, and should tell you what would be involved in adding the panel.  This will give you a better understanding of what your options are, and an idea of how much it would cost to simply have a professional handle the job.